# Raiz n-esima JAVA

Tags: java

Buenas tengo el siguiente codigo de una funcion recursiva la cual tuve que pasar de un while a recursion, pero me esta tirando un error de infinito y no se como solucionarlo o si mi logica es correcta.

```
public static float nthPower(float x, int n) {
        float tmp = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            tmp = tmp * x;
        }

        return tmp;
    }
    
    public static float nthRootz(float x, int n){
        float result = 0f;
        float aux = 0.00001f;
        System.out.println("Parte 1");
        return nthRoot(x, n, result, aux);
    }

    public static float nthRoot(float x, int n, float result, float aux) {
        if(nthPower(result, n) > x){
            return result;
        } else{
            result = result + aux;
            return nthRoot(x, n, result, aux);
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Un incremento de 0.0001? Para calcular la raíz cuadrada de 64 con incremento de 0.00001 necesitaría 80000 llamadas recursivas de la función. Usa `Math.pow(64,1/n)` donde n es la raíz enésima que quieres calcular. Si necesitas implementarlo revisa por favor [algoritmos de la raíz enésima](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radicaci%C3%B3n#C%C3%A1lculo_de_la_ra%C3%ADz_en%C3%A9sima). No reinventes la rueda.